# How to combine these two SELECT statment inside one

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a MySQL query something like this:

```
if($wr_id) {
            $sql = "SELECT 
                        csi.*, 
                        aa.Name 
                    FROM 
                        completed_supplier_invoices csi
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles aa
                    ON 
                        aa.Id = csi.MaterialArticleId
                    WHERE 
                        aa.AtaId = $ata_id
                    AND 
                        aa.wrId = $wr_id";
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT 
                        csi.*, 
                        aa.Name 
                    FROM 
                        completed_supplier_invoices csi
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles aa
                    ON 
                        aa.Id = csi.MaterialArticleId
                    WHERE 
                        aa.AtaId = $ata_id";
        }
```

And I need to write these query in `Oracle SQL` and since I  don't have enought experience in `Oracle SQL` I am a little bit confusing here with these two `SELECT` statements.

So far I try to use `UNION` but I am not sure if this is good solution and so far not sure if result is correct.

Can someone guide me and tell me how to solve this problem?

I would be very thankful

My solution

```
 SELECT 
                        csi.*, 
                        aa.Name 
                    FROM 
                        completed_supplier_invoices csi
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles aa
                    ON 
                        aa.Id = csi.MaterialArticleId
                    WHERE 
                        aa.AtaId = 2014
                    AND 
                        aa.wrId = 355
                        UNION
                     SELECT 
                        csi.*, 
                        aa.Name 
                    FROM 
                        completed_supplier_invoices csi
                    INNER JOIN 
                        ata_articles aa
                    ON 
                        aa.Id = csi.MaterialArticleId
                    WHERE 
                        aa.AtaId = 2014
```

Comment: "Not sure if result is correct" - well, you have your data, so test if the result is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT 
    csi.*,
    aa.Name
FROM completed_supplier_invoices csi
INNER JOIN ata_articles aa
    ON aa.Id = csi.MaterialArticleId
WHERE
    aa.AtaId = $ata_id AND
    (aa.wrId = $wr_id OR $wr_id IS NULL);
```

When `$wr_id` is *not* defined (i.e. is `NULL`), the second condition in the `WHERE` clause which appears in the first query effectively goes away.  When `$wr_id` is defined, then the query basically reduces the first one.

Comment: Thank you for solution and explanaition :)

Comment: @unknow_user You may have to play around with the above query to make it work from PHP.  Basically, you'd have to make sure that binding a null variable in PHP would translate to a SQL null (I'm pretty sure it would; but you still need to check this).

Comment: Sure, I will check one more time will this work but as far as I see it works perfect